# What method should be used to compare fit of different GAMs?

Tags: regression, r, generalized-additive-model, model-comparison, mgcv

I am building GAMs of the following form (using `R`'s `mgcv` notation) and would like to compare the fit between each model.

```
model1 <- gam(dependent_var ~ metric +
                             s(latitude,longitude) + 
                             s(UNIT, bs = 're'),
                             data  = df)
model2 <- gam(dependent_var ~ metric2 +
                             s(latitude,longitude) + 
                             s(UNIT, bs = 're'),
                             data  = df)
```

I would normally think to use AIC or a LRT to compare fit, but note that the difference between the models is only  `metric` and `metric2`, i.e., the models are not truncated versions of one-another.

Another option I have considered is to build training and testing datasets, and compare the sum of the residuals in the testing dataset to compare fit. Is there a proper way to compare fit using two, non-truncated GAMs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Answer

For GAMs, one does not need nested models for AIC/BIC comparison. Simon Wood even notes this in his canonical book on GAMS (p.110) and later discusses this in much greater detail in p.301.

> Models under comparison need not be nested, although some neglected terms in the approximation of the expected K-L divergence will cancel if they are.

##### Reference

Wood, S. N. (2017). Generalized additive models: An introduction with R (2nd ed.). CRC Press, Taylor and Francis Group.

Comment: To confirm, AIC is still useful under the same rules (smaller = better fit) when using non nested GAMs?

Comment: It's not just for GAMs, AIC in general does not require nested models.

Comment: @geoscience123 yes, lower scores are preferred and as Gavin noted this applies across contexts.